# Mysql create symbolic link to a table from another database

Tags: mysql

As stated the title, is it possible to have a "virtual copy" or "symbolic link" of/to a table from another database ?

Let's consider as an example two database : DB_A and DB_B. Assume that in DB_A, there is a table named TBL1

I would like to create in DB_B a 'virtual table' DB_B.TBL1 which is linked to DBA.TBL1. When one table is updated, it's brother also. One important thing is that data must not be stored twice.

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: What do you mean by when someone get updated his brother as well and in the same way no data sorted twice? do you want only the schema of the table or what exactly ? if you want to access a table from another database you just use DB_A.TBL1

Comment: Just use `DB_A.TBL1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating an [updatable view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html).

> MySQL supports views, including updatable views. Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set. A view acts as a virtual table.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html

Comment: The OP said data must not be stored twice.. the view is a virtual table storing the result of query

Comment: @AnouarZBAIDA Data isn't stored twice. From the docs: "Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set" -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html

Comment: @AnouarZBAIDA When the data is stored twice, this is known as a "materialized view", which isn't what I'm suggesting here.

Comment: Put me in the picture, I am learning.. the view create a virtual table in database and fill the table with the result of the query excuted.. so basicly the information stored in a table and in the virtual table AKA view.. is this correct or I am missing something ?

Comment: You described a "materialized view". A regular view is just stored as a query. When you query a view, it runs the stored query and filters the results based on your query.

Comment: You are right, I did some research. `Materialized views are disk based and are updated periodically based upon the query definition. Views are virtual only and run the query definition each time they are accessed.`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I'm so happy !!! Could someone give a few words about algorithm / cascaded checked option and local checked option ?

Comment: @Imabot Please post a separate question for that follow up question. Also, if you've found this answer helpful, please mark it correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Imabot check this out https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/sqlp/rbafywithcascade.htm

Comment: If the mysql user has access to both databases you can just specify the database in the select and Mysql retrieves the value from the other database's table... select table1.field1, DB_B.table2.field2 from table1...

Comment: Thank you Jorge. You are right, I knew this but I don't want to manage to connections to the database.